# Swipe in listView makes the link shrink

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I followed a guide to add swipe to my listView.
Basically there is a gesture listener on each row, when swiping the visibility of the back layout is set to visible and the buttons appear, while the front layout disappears

Unfortunately, whenever I swipe, the dimension of the row shrinks back to that of the buttons I want to show after swiping.

[after swiping the row shrinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWcyV.png)

[for better comprehension, with visibility of both backgrounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU8sP.png)

(sorry can't post images yet)

how do I keep the same height when showing the buttons?
(mind that rows' height might vary)

list_item_swipeable.xml (for each row)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_front"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_link"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_origin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_created_at"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_back"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"
            android:background="@color/btn_delete_bg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/edit"
            android:background="@color/btn_edit_bg"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnDelete"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyGestureListener

```
public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final String TAG = "MyGestureListener";
    private RelativeLayout backLayout;
    private LinearLayout frontLayout;
    private Animation inFromRight,outToRight,outToLeft,inFromLeft;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams frontParams;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams backParams;

    public MyGestureListener(Context ctx, View convertView) {
        backLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_back);
        frontLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_front);
        inFromRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.in_from_right);
        outToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.out_to_right);
        outToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.out_to_left);
        inFromLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.in_from_left);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                if(diffX<0){
                    Log.v(TAG, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    if(backLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        frontParams = frontLayout.getLayoutParams();

                        backParams = backLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d("HEIGHT FRONT ", ": "+frontParams.height ); // why -1?
                        Log.d("HEIGHT BACK ", ": "+backParams.height ); // why -1?

                        frontLayout.startAnimation(outToLeft);
                        backLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        backLayout.startAnimation(inFromRight);
                        frontLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    if(backLayout.getVisibility()!=View.GONE){
                        backLayout.startAnimation(outToRight);
                        backLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        frontLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        frontLayout.startAnimation(inFromLeft);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

getView method in my custom listAdapter

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_swipeable, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

//            holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            holder.container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

            holder.created_at = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_created_at);
            holder.link = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_link);
            holder.origin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_origin);

            holder.mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext, new MyGestureListener (mContext, convertView));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.created_at.setText( mData.get(position).getCreated_at());
        holder.link.setText( mData.get(position).getLink());
        holder.origin.setText( mData.get(position).getOrigin());



        holder.container.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                holder.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;



    }
```

Comment: When settings visibility to `View.GONE` (in `frontLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) you basically tell that this view should not be considered when measuring the parent view (list item), so parent view thinks that it is only as high as the buttons. To make some view invisible, but still be measured, use `View.INVISIBLE`

Comment: It partially works! now the line doesn't shrink (which is awesome) but the buttons don't expand in height and i get this http://imgur.com/z64EayV

Comment: This is typical buggy behavior of `RelativeLayout` when used on the list and children want to match it's height. Please use `FrameLayout` as a root view in this case and set height to `wrap_content` (`match_parent` is not supported as a list item anyway). Also you should not have the situation that every children of root view that both have height as `match_parent`. The parent (root view) has to calculate it's view based on something. Please change height of `layout_front` to `wrap_content` and set `minHeight` on it with the value equals of the icons height.

Comment: IT WORKS! thank you!!! you saved my day